# Entity Framework: One to zero/one with C# Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Sorry in advance if this has been answered somewhere, but I searched around and could not find the answer.

I am trying to link up UserProfile and Reviewer tables. Reviewer is a type of users in the application, so the relationship between the two tables is one (UserProfile) to zero/one (Reviewer).

The UserProfile model is:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Reviewer Reviewer { get; set; }
}
```

Reviewer Class:

```
public class Reviewer
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int ReviewerID { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
    // other properties of Reviewer...

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

}
```

In other words I am trying to set the foreign key UserId as the key of the table Reviewer, with the name as ReviewerID.

I specify the fluent API as the following:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        // other fluent API...

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.Reviewer).WithRequired(x => x.UserProfile);

    }
```

However, the database generated by Code First is not quite what I wanted.

Suppose I have the following entry in the UserProfile table: 
UserId = 4, UserName = lostman1

and I try to manually insert a new record to the Reviewer table: 
ReviewerID = 4, Email = d@d.com

It turns out that I cannot update the ReviewerID field in the database cause it is an auto-incremented field. Moreover, I get the following error:

> The data in row 4 was not committed.
>   Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider.
>   Error Message: A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key > value does not exist. [Foreign key constraint name =  FK_dbo.Reviewer_dbo.UserProfile_ReviewerID]

Whats wrong with my code first setup? Many thanks!

Comment: try something like this in your fluent and add a foreign key `int? ReviewerId` to your userprofile. `HasOptional(t => t.Organization)
                .WithMany(t => t.Configurations)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.OrganizationID);`

Comment: Sorry I am new to asp.net MVC. I try: modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasOptional(x => x.Reviewer).WithRequired(x => x.UserProfile).HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId); but it returns with compile error. Can you help me to write down the exact fluent API statement that I need to put in, or point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you need to have a UserID FK relationship between Reviewer and User. In such a design, not all users would have to be reviewers, but all reviewers would have to be a user.

I also am starting to think that maybe you are over-complicating things by no utilizing a concept of roles within your system. Generally, a user vs reviewer would be specified depending upon the roles that a user has. In this manner, all users would be the same and hold the same data in the tables, the only difference would be that the users have different roles.

Authorization and authentication also become simplified when using Roles vs doing complicated table joining or nullable FK relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact in my application there are different types of users, such as Approver. However, different types of users have different relationships with other tables. For example, table Reviewer has a many to one relationship with table Reviewer_class, but table Approver has many to one relationship with Approver_class. I can't encapsulate this differences if I only assign different user types into different roles, I also need to link up the tables in the database to represent these relationships. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but your design could be accomplished with smaller junction tables and roles. For instance, you could have a junction table that joins Users with Reviews, and then let role management determine if a user is a Reviewer.

Comment: Sorry I am new to web programming and asp.net, so I don't quite understand. How can role management to determine if a user is a reviewer? In fact there are many types of users in my application, each with different types of profiles (stored with different details of the users) and relationships with other entities. I think role management is only for authorizing who have access to a resource. How can I use it to help me in this aspect? Is there any tutorial about what you have mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check [this](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model) for role management.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem is solved,if not, you can try something like this

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(x => x.Reviewer).WithRequired(x => x.User).Map(x => x.MapKey("UserId"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

And here are my model declaration

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Reviewer Reviewer { get; set; }
}
public class Reviewer
{
    [Key]
    public int ReviewerId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```